# how to set variable value in form action?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, action

is it possible to set variable value in html form action?

```
 var serverUrl=homeURL + "/runapp?requestType=Import&subRequestType=importScenario&userName=";

 refButton = '<form id="importForm" action="serverUrl" class="userInputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
        '<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />' +
        '</form>';
```

Comment: what does the var in `action="var"` refer to?

Comment: I think only with PHP on page load

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom sorry its serverUrl now i will edit

Comment: ah oke :P I was about to answer that

Comment: `'<form id="importForm" action="'+serverUrl+'" class="userInputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean insert the value of the variable?  Why wouldn't it?  In this case you're creating an HTML string to return, so something like this should work:

`returnedHTML = '<form action="'+JSvariable+'" id="myId>`

or

`returnedHTML = '<form action="<?=$phpVariable?>" id="myId>`